# Use literal negative indices in list

Tags: python, list, indexing

Usually in Python if we put `lst[-1]` we mean the item at the length of `lst`. But I would like to make it where it means "before index 0". Is such a thing possible? I've looked around but I haven't found anything useful yet.

Currently I'm working on a robot that maps out a room. The indices will be used for coordinates in the room so if my robot starts at `(0, 0)` in a 2d list then I need to be able to traverse the X & Y axes in both the positive and negative directions. that is why I need this I need to be able to use `0` as not the beginning of the list but rather is just a part of the list.

Comment: What do you think is there before index 0?

Comment: There's nothing before zero. You're almost certainly solving your problem (whatever it might be) in the wrong way.

Comment: Mind give us an example?

Comment: sure `go_to = lambda index,a_list: a_list[index] if index > 0 else "You are in OZ"`

Comment: Currently I'm working on a robot that Maps out a room I don't want to go too much into detail but basically the indices will be used for coordinates in the room so if my robot starts at 00 in a 2d list then I need to be able to traverse  the X & Y axes in both the positive and negative coordinates. that is why I need this I need to be able to use 0 as not the beginning of the list but rather is just a part of the list if this is not possible then I will find a workaround

Comment: Use a dictionary, and `d[-1]` can be whatever you want.

Comment: @ChristopherJakob You need to find a way to translate your co-ordinates into list indices not the other way around. Lists (or arrays) counts from ZERO.

Comment: Thanks guys! @joranBeasley fair to say that the coordinate api allows for values to be stored in coordinate locations?

Comment: Subclass `list` and write `__getitem__` to work however you want.

Comment: Thanks everyone going to put my nose in the docs now that I know What I'm looking for

Comment: For a room of 100 rows, you could emulate a range of -50 to 50 by simply adding 50: `robot_location = -20`, `room[robot_location+50][column])`.

Comment: Like @TigerhawkT3 said, simply add the "before-space" at the end and interpret the negative indexes as "before". I mean, up to you how you think of them. I've done this a couple times, can be quite useful. No need for dicts or lambda or subclassing list or translating coordinates. Don't know what the guys were thinking.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin. Sounds like what you need is a hashmap that can take arbitrary values as keys. That's called a dictionary! :)

Comment: @StefanPochmann it's not clear if the map has a defined size. If you don't know if the room is 10x10 or 10000x10000, it's silly to try to create a list to hold all that data. Just create a `cur_map = {0: {0: "I am here!"}}`, travel one square South and do `cur_map[0][-1] = "New square"` and etc.

Comment: @StefanPochmann this is perfect for a `collections.defaultdict`. `cur_map = collections.defaultdict(dict)`, `cur_map[0][0] = "START!"`

Comment: Since the only apparent problem with using a `list` was a coordinate system shifted by half of the `list`'s length, indexing by the coordinate plus half of the `list`'s length seems like the most appropriate solution.

Comment: @AdamSmith I suggest you read the question again. At least the title. It literally asks *"in python can we make a negative indices mean before zero?"*. And the answer is a clear "Yes, you can". I talked about that, and I don't see any need for anything else.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 unless the length of the list is unknown at runtime, of course~

Comment: @AdamSmith Let's also presume that he needs it to be very fast and suggest he should use C++, shall we?

Comment: That would have just as much of an impact on using `room[coordinate+0.5*len(room)][column]` as it would on using a `list` at all. So, if the only problem was a coordinate system with negative numbers, a bit of addition would suffice.

Comment: @StefanPochmann did you read OP's comment? He's talking about using a robot to map a room. Assuming that the room size is not known to the program at runtime isn't wildly out of scope.

Comment: Ah darn, I actually misinterpreted @TigerhawkT3 ... What *I'm* talking about is *not* shifting but simply *interpreting* the negative indexes as being "before". Doesn't matter that they come later in memory.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I agree, which is why I advocated against using a 2D list!

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes, I did read that, and it suggests that lists suffice for him. And that his only problem is negative indexes.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Maybe you're okay doing tons of extra inserts as the size of the list changes, but that's not smart code.

Comment: The OP might be mapping the contents of a room of known size.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 it's possible! I'd rather avoid assuming that, but you're welcome to write up an answer using the index offset method

Comment: The size of the room is unknown the full idea. Map the parameter of the room then fill the room with coordinates all coordinates start with 1 meaning that spot has not been cleaned. When the robot passes by a coordinate change it to 2 meaning cleaned. Using ultra sound avoid obsticals if obstical is found change coordinate to 0 meaning dead zone, can't go there that's what I am working to achieve. I hope this answers all questions thanks everyone

Comment: In that case, you'd probably be better off with a dictionary, as @Adam suggested.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your program won't know how big the room is when it's run, since it's using a robot to map it. In which case let's stop trying to use list indexes and use something better-suited to the task of handling arbitrary keys.

```
from collections import defaultdict

cur_map = defaultdict(dict)
```

This creates a `dict` object that, when you assign an unknown key to it, creates a new `dict` as a value. In other words:

```
cur_map[0]['foo'] = 'bar'
# cur_map now looks like
# {0: {'foo': 'bar'}}
```

Dictionaries can take arbitrary hashable objects as keys, so you can do

```
cur_map[0][0] = "START"
cur_map[0][-1] = "South x1"
cur_map[-1][-1] = "South x1, West x1"
# etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If you for example want a 2D list with x-indexes -50 to 50 and y-indexes -50 to 50, then simply make a 101x101 list and *interpret* negative indexes as being "before". Up to you how you think of them.

I've used this before, for example in a maze puzzle, to avoid boundary-checking in my main code. I simply added two rows and two columns in addition to the actual field and put "walls" in the cells of the two last rows and columns. Index -1 then simply represented the row above the one of index 0 and the column left of the one with index 0.

Comment: This is a great approach for games that require implicit boundary checking, though you may still get weird crashes when IndexErrors happen! :)